# How to separate files of an multipart/form-data answer

Tags: python, file, download

I connect via Python to a web interface, where I get back as response files in *multipart/form-data* format. 
I know the format type only when a browser responds to a form, but here the server sends its response in this format.

How can I get the original file from this answer without the metadata of the interface? 
I have here a few examples with one, two, three and four contents.
I have no idea how to solve it and ask for your help.

I uploaded the files to zippyshare, because is to big for text view.
http://www22.zippyshare.com/v/EEXIbj79/file.html

http://www22.zippyshare.com/v/eXF62wpq/file.html

http://www22.zippyshare.com/v/sSi9crCT/file.html

http://www22.zippyshare.com/v/RiXF57WD/file.html

Thank you in advance

Comment: maybe it is possible with https://pythonhosted.org/circuits/api/circuits.web.parsers.multipart.html ? but how?

Answer (score 1):

for http/s this works for me.

```
r = requests.get(URL, headers={'Connection': 'close'})
boundary = r.headers["Content-Type"].split(";", 1)[1].strip().replace("boundary=", "", 1)
comps = Content.split(boundary.encode())
```